# Print WPF grid without GridLines

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printdialog

I have grid array and I want to print all the grid.each grid have in his cell textbox
the grid set to `ShowGridLines = false;` and also I have a method the remove the textbox border.

```
private void DeletBorder()
{
    Thickness bor = new Thickness(0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.gridArray.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.gridArray[i].Children)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                ((TextBox) ctrl).BorderThickness = bor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to print all the grids in the array with this method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
        this.DeletBorder();
        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            this.DeletBorder();
            foreach (Grid item in this.gridArray)
            {
                printDlg.PrintVisual(item, "Stiker Print Job");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you must select the page layout first");
    }
}
```

but the result is that only the first page printed without border/gridLines but the other still printed with border/gridLines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that, calling `this.DeleteBorder()` twice is pointless.

Secondly, assuming `gridArray` has only `Grid`s in it; you need to not show any grid lines for each `Grid.`  Try this:

```
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    /* remove this--this.DeletBorder(); */

    int index = 0;
    foreach(Grid item in this.gridArray)
    {
        item.ShowGridLines = false;
        // Add an identifier so you know what job is printing. You may need to call:
        // item.UpdateLayout();
        printDlg.PrintVisual(item, "Stiker Print Job: " + index.ToString());
    }
}
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, please provide some XAML and/or more sample code to recreate the issue on http://gist.github.com.